# Does tools:context affect apk?

Tags: android

In my project I observed that in an xml layout tools:context of parent layout is set to some other fragment instead of the right one. In production, when we check the visibility of 1 view from that layout, app is crashing with a null pointer exception saying that the view is null. We never faced this issue while testing though. Now my doubt is does this wrong context value cause the issue? I read that tools namespace doesn't get set to APK.I just wanted to know whether this matters as I couldn't find any other reason for the view to be null in the fragment. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: there are loads of reasons for why the view could be null, but the tools namespace probably isn't the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it does not, this attr just helps rendering `View` in preview tab in Android Studio

> Used by: Lint, Android Studio layout editor

> This attribute declares which activity this layout is associated with by default. This enables features in the editor or layout preview that require knowledge of the activity, such as what the layout theme should be in the preview...

from [DOC](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolscontext)

Comment: thanks @snachmsm. so the reason for view being null could be something else I assume.

Comment: thats for shure. maybe create new question, describe which `View` is `null` and post your logic handling this `View`